# Adding photo to float left in jQuery Accordion

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a functional jQuery Accordion.  I would like to add a photo inside the container and have it float left, making the text after the image float right - like having 2 columns.  I've attempted many scenarios with no avail.  This is my closest attempt:

```
 <!-- Accordion-->
  <section class="section-45 section-sm-45">
    <div class="shell">
      <div class="range">
        <div class="cell-md-12 cell-lg-12">
          <h5>Screening Products (beta)</h5>
          <hr>
          <!-- Responsive-tabs-->
          <div class="responsive-tabs responsive-tabs-horizontal" data-type="accordion">
            <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
              <li>Item 1</li>
              <li>Item 2</li>
              <li>Item 3</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="resp-tabs-container">
              <div class="animated fadeIn">

                <p><img src="images/placeholder270x270.jpg" alt="" />Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque 
                ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="animated fadeIn">
                <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque 
                ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="animated fadeIn">
                <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque 
                ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

I've tried to do CSS to float left, make width xx%, etc.  Nothing seems to work, I seem to fight the jQuery.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: can you add a working example that mimics the behavior, you will get more replies with a working snippet as no one has to configure the accordion themselves which reduces time an effort, you didnt even specified which accordion you are using there are several jquery accordions

Comment: I haven't added working snippet straight into Stack Overflow before.  If there's a way, please let me know.  Otherwise, here's a link to a functional page for reference: https://www.btswebdev.com/testsites/cjc/test.html. Let me know if this helps or if there's a better way to share.

Answer (score 0):

add some style.

```
.my-img {
   position: absolute;
   margin-left: 0px!important;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion.  Unfortunately, this will blow out the accordion container doing position: absolute.